# Is dataframe.show() an action in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following code:

```
val df_in = sqlcontext.read.json(jsonFile) // the file resides in hdfs

//some operations in here to create df as df_in with two more columns "terms1" and "terms2" 

val intersectUDF = udf( (seq1:Seq[String], seq2:Seq[String] ) => {     seq1 intersect seq2 } ) //intersects two sequences
val symmDiffUDF = udf( (seq1:Seq[String], seq2:Seq[String] ) => { (seq1 diff seq2) ++ (seq2 diff seq1) } ) //compute the difference of two sequences

val df1 = (df.withColumn("termsInt", intersectUDF(df("terms1"), df1("terms2") ) )
             .withColumn("termsDiff", symmDiffUDF(df("terms1"),     df1("terms2") ) )
             .where( size(col("termsInt")) >0 && size(col("termsDiff")) > 0 && size(col("termsDiff")) <= 2 )
             .cache()
           ) // add the intersection and difference columns and filter the resulting DF 

df1.show()
df1.count()
```

The app is working properly and fast until the `show()` but in the `count()` step, it creates 40000 tasks.

My understanding is that `df1.show()` should be triggering the full `df1` creation and  `df1.count()` should be very fast. What am I missing here? why is `count()` that slow?

Thank you  very much in advance,
Roxana

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`show` is indeed an action, but it is smart enough to know when it doesn't have to run everything. If you had an `orderBy` it would take very long too, but in this case all your operations are map operations and so there's no need to calculate the whole final table. However, `count` needs to physically go through the whole table in order to count it and that's why it's taking so long. You could test what I'm saying by adding an `orderBy` to `df1`'s definition - then it should take long.

**EDIT:** Also, the 40k tasks are likely due to the amount of partitions your DF is partitioned into. Try using `df1.repartition(<a sensible number here, depending on cluster and DF size>)` and trying out count again.

Comment: Yes, indeed... orderBy takes a long time.

Comment: `coalesce` is probably better than `repartition` as it avoids a shuffle.

Comment: Note taken for the future :)

Answer (score 5):

`show()` by default shows only 20 rows. If the 1st partition returned more than 20 rows, then the rest partitions will not be executed.

Note `show` has a lot of variations. If you run `show(false)` which means show all results, all partitions will be executed and may take more time. So, `show()` equals `show(20)` which is a **partial action**.

Comment: That means if I run show() or say show(10), only a single partition from the dataframe is brought to the driver and records are displayed right? @thebluephantom

Comment: @subhayang  if the 1st partition has enuff records, else it will look in others consecutively.

Comment: `show(false)` does not mean show all results, it still displays only 20 rows but includes all columns. To print more than 20 rows you need to pass number of rows into the method