# Is .show() a Spark action?

Tags: apache-spark

When one calls `show()` on a Spark dataframe, is this an "action" in the sens that the full calculation is actually performed? Clearly in order to show any results, some of a given calculation actually needs to be performed, but in some cases it may in principle be possible to show a subset of the results without performing the full calculation (analogous to using `LIMIT` in a SQL query).

This [documentation page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html#actions) lists "some of the common actions" but I wasn't able to find an exhaustive list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024624/is-dataframe-show-an-action-in-spark

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. Even now that you've pointed it out, I can't find that one via SO search unless I search for exactly "dataframe.show()".

Comment: Yes df.`show(20)` is an action with minimal overhead. internally it will call take(n)

Comment: yes, I was using google rather than stackoverflow search ;)